# MySQL Left join with count on second Table

Tags: mysql

I have looked through some of the other posts on this site and am not seeing exactly what im looking for so here goes.

Lets say i have 2 tables

```
juser
-----------------------------
userID   firstName   lastName
-----------------------------
1         billy        bob
2         jezze       belle
3         bobbie       sue
```

and:

```
juserrel
--------------------------------------------- 
id       userID      relUserID        state
--------------------------------------------- 
1         1            2            approved
2         2            1            retired
3         2            1            approved
4         3            2            approved
```

What i am trying to do is get a result set that shows each user info about each user in the juser table and adds a column called connections to the result set which shows how many "active" connections a particular user has to another user.

the result i expect based on the tables above is

```
resultSet
-----------------------------------------------
userID    firstName    lastName    connections
-----------------------------------------------
  1         billy        bob           2
  2         jezze        belle         3
  3         bobbie       sue           1
```

The query I tried is as follows

```
select userID, firstName, lastName , coalesce(x.cnt,0) as connections 
from juser
left outer join (select count(*) cnt from juserrel where juserrel.userID =
userID or juserrel.relatedUserID = userID and juserrel.state = 'approved') 
x on userID = userID
```

The result set i get looks like this:

```
resultSet
-----------------------------------------------
userID    firstName    lastName    connections
-----------------------------------------------
  1         billy        bob           4
  2         jezze        belle         4
  3         bobbie       sue           4
```

Help Please ;)

Comment: yes  i edited that .. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select u.userID, u.firstName, u.lastName,
    count(case when ur.state = 'approved' then 1 end)
from juser u
inner join juserrel ur on u.userID = ur.userID or u.userID = ur.relUserID
group by u.userID, u.firstName, u.lastName
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d23/17)

Comment: That will compute that user #2 (Jezze Belle) has three active connections, but the OP specifies that she has only two (presumably because two of the relationships are both with user #1, one in each direction). I think you need to use `DISTINCT` or `UNION` somewhere in there.

Comment: @ruakh I think you are right, that was not clear from question.

Comment: ohh my fault - yes user 2 should have 3 active connections

Comment: Updated with SQL Fiddle example.